# Why is JQuery return acting the way it is?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a silverstripe portal for moodle; the below code is for using silverstripe avatars in moodle.

To do this I created a a JQuery script to grab the image from silverstripe site (which is named a users moodle id) and replace the moodle one, with a fall back to moodle default pic if it doesn't exist.

```
$(".userpicture").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", function(i, origValue){
        $(this).attr( "onerror", "this.onerror=null;this.src=\'" + origValue + "\'");
/*code for generating imgsrc */
        return imgsrc;
    });
});
```

Worked fine, but I could only have it work for one file extension.
So after trying many different methods of testing a url for a valid image I was able to alter my code to work for all extensions with use of a new image object. Or so I thought. This is where my question really comes into play.

The below code, regardless if the image is jpg or png it will test all the way to bmp and return that:

```
$(".userpicture").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", function(i, origValue){
        $(this).attr( "onerror", "this.onerror=null;this.src=\'" + origValue + "\'");
/*code for generating imgsrc */

        var image = new Image();

        image.src = imgsrc + ".jpg";
        if(image.width) {
           return imgsrc + ".jpg";          
        } else {
            image.src = imgsrc + ".png" ;

            if(image.width) {
               return image.src;
            }  else {
               image.src = imgsrc + ".gif" ;
               if(image.width) {
                  return image.src;
               }  else {
                  image.src = imgsrc + ".bmp" ;

                  if(image.width) {
                      return image.src;
                  }
              }
           }
       }
    });
});
```

Why does it act like this? Surely the return statement should end the function and return?

My search for an answer brought me to many explanations about .each() function and how it has unique rules around the return statement, which at first I thought explained it but the return statements aren't tied to the .each() function but rather the function inside that .attr() so it couldn't possibly be that.

I am utterly confused by this.

To make matters more confusing is that I created a working solution by creating a new image object for each test. This somehow makes it stop once it has found a valid image and not continue the testing.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = imgsrc + ".jpg";
    if(image.width) {
        return imgsrc + ".jpg";
    } else {
        var image2 = new Image();
        image2.src = imgsrc + ".png" ;

        if(image2.width) {
            return image2.src;
        }  else {
            var image3 = new Image();
            image3.src = imgsrc + ".gif" ;

            if(image3.width) {
                return image3.src;
            }  else {
                var image4 = new Image();
                image4.src = imgsrc + ".bmp" ;

                if(image4.width) {
                    return image4.src;  
                }
```

But again why is this? Does it have something to do with the image object? Even if that were the case the return statements in the original code should still have worked?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the comments from Felix Kling and charlietft I have learnt that it is because the request is asynchronous and was completing before the images were loaded. And the second code was only appearing to work due to caching of the images.

**EDIT2:**

Learning why this isn't possible I re-evaluated what I wanted, and changed my thinking and have come up with this working solution:

```
 var startExt = "jpg";
$(".userpicture").each(function() {


    changeImage($(this),startExt);

 });

 function changeImage(item, ext){
        $(item).attr("src", function() {

        if( ext === "jpg") {
            item.attr( "onerror", "changeImage( $(this), \'png\')");
        } else if( ext === "png") {
            item.attr( "onerror", "changeImage( $(this), \'gif\')");
        } else if( ext === "gif") {
            item.attr( "onerror", "changeImage( $(this), \'bmp\')");
        } 

        /*  Code to create img url */

        return imgurl + "." + ext;

        });
    }
```

As you can see I opted for a recursive call onerror whenever an extension failed, in opposed to testing all the extensions for a valid url.
Still not 100% happy with it, but it's better than it was and I feel I learnt more about JQuery.

Comment: can't check dimensions of image until it has loaded. Your code will run infinitely faster than the request to get the image

Comment: Did you try to log the values of each `image.width`? Also you need to learn about [loops](http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_oupMC+5FKN).

Comment: Why would that be case? The code shouldn't move onto the next else until image.width is checked, like it does with the second example.

Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: the request is asynchronous ... your code doesn't pause to wait for it

Comment: At the moment you check `image.width`, the image wasn't loaded yet. I doubt that your second version actually works (assuming the image wasn't already cached). Your whole question is based on the assumption that `if (image.width)` is successful, but it is not.

Comment: Then why does the second code work? Surely it shouldn't if this were the case. Because it is loading more images.

But it stops on the first image if jpg, second image if png etc etc

Comment: ah ha! Thank you Felix, that suddenly brings some light to the matter.

I just tested with changing the image, gave a couple failed loads and then success. Guess it is a caching thing causing the second to work.

Ok gives me something to think about now.

Comment: Yeah, this shows that it can't work: https://jsfiddle.net/au2domfm/ .